# Partial Logging to filesystem on IIS in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, logging

I have a very weird behaviour of my ASP.NET web application on .NET 4.6.1 using C#. When I log information to file system on IIS it seems doesn't work properly. In VS environment everything is working fine and the log file appear to be like expected.

I use to setup my environment and my own logging system in the `global.asax` `Application_Start` event handler, at apppool start.

I initialize my log file like \location\myapp20180606.log and write a couple of row like "application start", "version bla bla"

The weird is that I use the same way to write these two lines in the global.asax and the standard log in all the other pages.

On VS environment I can see the full Log file is populated.

Once I publish on IIS the log file contains only the two lines of global asax, no clue of the all other lines.

This is the code, hoping there is something wrong I didn't see

```
public void Log(string msg, logLevel level = logLevel.Debug)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg))  
        return;

    string now = String.Format(@"{0:hh:mm:ss:sss}", DateTime.Now);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)) 
        UserName = "SYSTEM";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Application)) 
        Application = "*unknow app*";

    string lvl = "";

    switch (level)
    {
            case logLevel.Action: lvl = "ACT"; break;
            case logLevel.Debug: lvl = "DBG"; break;
            case logLevel.Info: lvl = "INF"; break;
            case logLevel.Error: lvl = "ERR"; break;
            case logLevel.Fatal: lvl = "FTL"; break;
            case logLevel.Warning: lvl = "WAR"; break;
    }

    string line = now + "|" + UserName + "|" + Application + "|" + lvl + "|" + msg;

    if(FileValid)  
        AppendToFile(LogFile, line);
}

public static bool AppendToFile(string nomeFile, string testo, bool addNewline = true, bool deletefirst = false)
{
        try
        {
            if (nomeFile == "") return false;
            StreamWriter fs;

            if (!File.Exists(nomeFile))
            {
                string cartella = Path.GetDirectoryName(nomeFile);

                if (cartella != null && !Directory.Exists(cartella))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(cartella);

                fs = new StreamWriter(nomeFile, false);
            }
            else
            {
                if (deletefirst)
                    File.Delete(nomeFile);

                fs = new StreamWriter(nomeFile, true);
            }

            if (addNewline)
                fs.WriteLine(testo);
            else
                fs.Write(testo);

            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In global.asax

```
LogFile = file + "_" + String.Format(@"{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Now) + ".log";

string line = "Ora|UserName|Application|Severita|Messaggio";
FileValid = AppendToFile(LogFile, line);
```

and wherever in the app

```
log("test msg");
```

What is happening is that in the visual studio environment I can see the full generated log.

Once I publish to IIS, I see only the two lines generated in the `global.asax` and anything else.

It looks like after the pool is started are set up some policies that does not allow me to write to file system, but I am unable to find where, how.

Thanks for help

Comment: How are you calling this logging function? Directly, from the worker threads? Are you familiar with the hazards of using multiple threads to access the same resources?

Comment: There are multiple logging frameworks (eg. nlog, Log4Net) that will log to files (and many other targets): don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I know Log4Net but I always used my own DLL and this worked on other apps without problems. Consider that within the IDE works as expected. Why the pool should be splitted in multiple thread? the pool is one thread, there are no async calls, I log on webform pages like Load_page events, it shoulbe be a normal thread..

Comment: Yes John Wu, my calls are direct, suppose in the master page, at every Load_Page and in lot of other places. I could understand if something wrong and the log doesnt work, but watching the first two lines is getting me confoused. why?!

Comment: concerning reinventing the wheel sotty Richard, Log4Net is something paleholitic that should be removed from NuGet, but is my opinion. btw the DLL doesnt created the moon, it does just what you saw, writes a string to file, its a basic stuff

Comment: If you are exposing this in a web site it is going to run on multiple threads. I can't really guess what is going on, but if you stop swallowing `Exception` ([don't do that!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx)), you might be surprised what shows up.

Comment: Also, you need to use `using` or `finally` with those disposable objects.

Comment: mm that makes sense, AppendToFile could run on exception, the streamwriter is not disposed and I dont see anything. Multiple thread cant be the issue because before to use it I check if the object is null, in that case I instanciate it again, so, it might run on multiple thread it should stil log in any circumnstances. I go back to the inventing the wheel. The topic is not about the way to log, I could have the need to write text files, the result would be the same. Let me add more control on the Exception and see what happen, thank you John!